# error in sending data to remote php server from react native app

Tags: php, android, react-native

I am trying to send data from my react native app to my remote app server written in PHP, here is the code snippet it:

```
fetch('http://172.20.10.2/fyp/products.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
  //passing input data to server
    cid: this.state.category_id

  })
```

Here is the PHP code where I am trying to receive data from my react native app:

```
// Getting the received JSON into $json variable.

 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

 // decoding the received JSON and store into $obj variable.
 $obj = json_decode($json,true);

$obj_id = $obj['cid'];
```

For debugging, I am printing `$obj_id` to a .txt file but it is printing nothing which indicates I am not receiving the data in my server. How do I resolve this?

Comment: please add JSON datatype headers to send json
 ` headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },`

Answer (score 0):

At the very top of your php file add

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");

And try again!